# How to migrate user's password from yii 1 to yii 2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, user-management

I have an Yii application, and now I need to revamp this Yii application to Yii 2, and I need to migrate the user table from Yii to Yii2. 
So how can I migrate the user's password so that user can login to Yii2 without changing password?

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite two methods in `User` model:

```
/**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }

    /**
     * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }
```

Rewrite to your methods from yii1 behavior